# How does unexpand command really work?

Tags: coreutils, tabulation

I've already read some explananations about unexpand, but either I don't understand, or is not working as expected.

Let's consider the following example:

```
[root@hope log]# echo "A12345678B" | tr '[1-8]' ' ' | unexpand -a
A        B
[root@hope log]# echo "A12345678B" | tr '[1-8]' ' ' | unexpand -a | od -ta
0000000   A  ht  sp   B  nl
0000005
[root@hope log]# echo "A12345678B12345678C" | tr '[1-8]' ' ' | unexpand -a | od -ta
0000000   A  ht  sp   B  ht  sp  sp   C  nl
0000011
[root@hope log]# echo "12345678" | tr '[1-8]' ' ' | unexpand -a | od -ta
0000000  ht  nl
0000002
```

I see that it replaces 8 blanks with one tab, but it appends one more space each time it appears some non-blank character.

Using bash-4.3.42-3.fc23.x86_64 and coreutils-8.24-6.fc23.x86_64

Please could you explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 7):

The `unexpand` program does not simply replace 8 spaces with a tab.  It replaces spaces and tabs in the line with the assumption that a tab causes the terminal used to display the line to move to the next *tabstop*.  Normally those are at intervals of 8 spaces, but for most terminals the interval can be changed (and the interval for each stop can be changed).

The first example string `"A12345678B"` replaces the digits 1-8 with spaces.  The first 8 characters in the result are one tab interval.  That leaves a space (where the 8 was) at the first tabstop.  The `unexpand` program does not *add* a space; that is left over after `unexpand` replaces the spaces in 1-7 with a tab.

One would use `unexpand` to convert a file containing mostly spaces (or a mixture of spaces and tabs) to a consistent format using tabs.  A file with many lines beginning with spaces can be much larger than one using tabs for the same reason (*indenting*).  Also, it is used to convert a file to use *different* tab stops, e.g., for a table whose columns align with one set of tab stops, making it wider or narrower.

A conversion between different tab intervals might be done like this:

```
expand -t 1,6,11,16,21 foo | unexpand -t 1,9,17,25,33 >bar
```

Besides tab stops set in the *terminal*, some programs (such as `vi`) can display text with different tab intervals.

Further reading

- [unexpand - convert spaces to tabs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unexpand.html) (POSIX)
- [tabs - set terminal tabs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tabs.html) (POSIX)
- [expand - convert tabs to spaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html) (POSIX)

Comment: Still I don't understand what is unexpand use for...

Comment: In the last example, however, there is no space left over, only an Horizontal Tab, why?

Comment: The space after the tab is because *that* character happens to be just past the tab-stop.