# How does unexpand command work with more than one tablist?

Tags: posix, whitespace

I tried reading the manual for unexpand as well as read the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269772/how-does-unexpand-command-really-work) but I do not understand how unexpand works with a tablist as an argument.

When I try the following (2 spaces and 3 spaces expecting them to converted to tabstops)

```
$ unexpand -t 2,3,4
  12**345***678
```

I get

```
12\t\t345***678
```

`*` represents a space (I used `*` for clarity). I'm not sure why there are two tabstops after 2 and no tabstops after 5 even though there are 3 blanks.

I also tried the following (expecting blanks in the 2nd and 5th columns to be converted to tabstops)

```
$ unexpand -t 2,5
  1*23*4567
```

I get

```
1*23*4567
```

I also tried

```
$ unexpand -t 2,5
  1**2*****345
```

I get

```
1\t*2*****345
```

I can't understand how the program interprets the tablist argument when there is more than one arg.

Comment: I would say it's broken and needs a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

`unexpand` does the reverse of `expand`. If you do `unexpand -t 2,3,4 | expand -t 2,3,4`, you should get back to the original.

The numbers are not the distance between the tabs, but their position (there distance from the left of the screen).

With `-t 2,3,4` you're setting the first tab stop at offset 2 (third column), second at offset 3, third at offset 4, and that's it.

```
  ↓↓↓
0123456
$ printf '%b|\n' '\t' '\t\t' '\t\t\t' | expand -t2,3,4
  |
   |
    |
```

The 1, 2, 3 tabstops are located at:

```
  123
```

If you match that against your:

```
  123
12**345***678
```

The `3` is at the third tabstop, so you need two tabs after `2` to get there, the first tab gets you to the second tabstop (as you've already reached the first), and the second to the third tab stop. There is not tab stop after than so your spaces are not converted to tabs.

If you wanted the second tab stop to be 3 columns after the second, and the third to be 4 columns after the second, you'd need `-t 2,5,9`:

```
  ↓  ↓   ↓
0123456789
$ printf '\t1\t2\t3\n' | expand -t 2,5,9
  1  2   3
```

Then you'd get:

```
          ↓  ↓   ↓
        01234567890
$ echo '12  345   678' | unexpand -t 2,5,9 | sed -n l
12  345\t 678$
```

Beware of the differences between (`un`)`expand` and `tabs` (the command that sets the tabstops of your terminal for those that support it):

- for `tabs`, columns are numbered from 1 instead of 0
- you use `tabs -8` (instead of `expand -t 8`) to set  tabstops every 8 columns (in effect, like `tabs 9 17 25 33...`, though you can also use `tabs 9 +8 +8 +8...`).

Comment: So, at the offsets, if there is a blank, it will be replaced with a \t? Like `unexpand -t2,3,6 "12**34*5"` will set columns 3, 4 and 5 to \t if these columns previously contained blanks? Here since I have blanks at offsets 2,3 and 6 I expected output "12\t\t34\t5" but I get "12\t*34*5".